# Which organisms have their cell wall made of polysaccharides and amino acids?

Tags: biochemistry, homework, classification

I came across a question which somewhat goes like

> In which of the following kingdom, **most** of the members have a cell wall made of **polysaccharide** and **amino acids** ? - **Monera** or **Fungi**.

To me it looks like both are correct answers because both are having hetero polymers of glucose and amine. Please enlighten me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is **Monera**.

It is so because their cell wall is made up of [peptidoglycan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptidoglycan).

> Peptidoglycan, also known as murein, is a polymer consisting of sugars and amino acids that forms a mesh-like layer outside the plasma membrane of most bacteria, forming the cell wall. The sugar component consists of alternating residues of β-(1,4) linked N-acetylglucosamine and N-acetylmuramic acid. Attached to the N-acetylmuramic acid is a peptide chain of three to five amino acids. The peptide chain can be cross-linked to the peptide chain of another strand forming the 3D mesh-like layer.

**Fungi** is wrong because its cell wall is made of [chitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin) which lacks amino acids.

> Chitin $(C_8H_{13}O_5N)_n$ is a long-chain polymer of an N-acetylglucosamine, a derivative of glucose, and is found in many places throughout the natural world. It is a characteristic component of the cell walls of fungi, the exoskeletons of arthropods such as crustaceans (e.g., crabs, lobsters and shrimps) and insects, the radulae of molluscs, and the beaks and internal shells of cephalopods, including squid and octopuses and on the scales and other soft tissues of fish and lissamphibians.